# How to parse email message as html format when there is no attachment

Tags: imap

I am new in using IMAP. Now I am trying to use IMAP to see my emails in my web page from mail server. I have configured the settings. And I think the configuration is ok. Now I want to show the message body as html format. My code is:

```
// getting email body text

if($attachments[1]['is_attachment']!=""){  // if attachmentavailable.
    $part_number = '1.2';
}
else{
    $part_number = '1';
}

$message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $part_number));
```

When email has attachment, it is showing as html format. But when there is no attachment the message is showing as plain text. There is no bold or any other formatted font if I give and there is no link also.
If I use part number 1.2 in else part no message is shown.
Now how can I print email message as html format where there is no attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about the `BODYSTRUCTURE` format. E-mails can come up in about a ton of different structures, and unless your application actually takes a look at the structure of the MIME message, your code is blindly guessing what to do.

Comment: To add to that... send yourself a message from gmail and again from iphone mail. Each message should contain three paragraphs interspersed with two pictures. Work with the bodystructure until your code can show both.

Comment: The structure is correct. Actually I want to know which part number will show the message as html format when there is no attachment in the message.

Comment: And the answer to that is "it depends". There's no magic number because the number depends on the structure of the message. Build and algorithm to read it, analyze it and determine the number. It's going to be different for different messages.